# vscode keeps crashing with "clean-exit" and code 0

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just got the error message "The window terminated unexpectedly (reason: 'clean-exit', code:'0')" while working in vs code. I had launched an app at this point in the integrated terminal, but apart from that did not do anything off.

I now am not able to start vscode anymore as even after uninstalling and reinstalling I keep getting the mentioned error.
OS: Ubuntu Mate

Is there any way of deleting the apparently saved session data without losing all my other configurations?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to delete `~/.vscode` and `~/.config/Code` to get going again. Thankfully all relevant configs regarding the workspace are stored in the `workspace.json` and could be restored.

Hope that helps if anybody encounters a similar problem.